# Bootstrap CSS -background color attributes have a * - Warning in Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I am getting lots of warnings in the Safari browser,

```
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (bootstrap.min.css, line 11)
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (bootstrap.min.css, line 47)
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (bootstrap.min.css, line 48)
```

The error is due to the * in front of the background-color.

```
.btn-danger:hover,.btn-danger:focus,.btn-danger:active,.btn-danger.active,.btn-danger.disabled,.btn-danger[disabled] {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #bd362f;
    *background-color: #a9302a;
}
```

Comment: Long ago, you could target IE with hacks like this. Put a `*` in front and only IE would recognise the selector. (This was caused by IE using different parsing rules and/or different error recovery methods than Netscape.) Not sure if that's still the case (can't test with IE now), but anyway, I have no idea why you would want to give something a different background color in IE than in other browsers. My advice, just get rid of it.